# django 2 Jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x

I'm having trouble getting my `autocomplete` box to show results. I'm not sure if I'm not importing something from Django that I need to. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

views.py

```
    def contact_name_search(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            q = request.GET.get('term','')
            names = PhoneBook.objects.filter(first_name__istartswith=q)
            result = []
            for n in names:
                name_json = n.full_name
                result.append(name_json)
            data = json.dumps(result)
        mimetype = 'application/json'
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

urls.py

```
    path('contact-name-search/', views.contact_name_search, name='contact-name-search'),
```

main.html

```
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="contact_name_search_input" name="contact_name_search" />
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#contact_name_search_input").autocomplete({
            source: "{% url 'contact-name-search' %}",
            minLength: 1,
            delay: 200,
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: change `name="contact_name_search"` to `name="term"`

Comment: Is your view actually called? Try to print `q` from inside the view to check that.

Comment: I tried changing the name; still doesn't work. I also tried printing `q`, it does not show anything. I don't that it is sending information. I have another AJAX search that works, and when I type a letter it shows in the terminal. When I type a letter in this one, it does not show in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize that `jQuery` and `jQuery.ui` were two seperate things. I wasn't linking `jQuery.ui`, and then when I did, it still didn't work, because I linked `jQuery.ui` before `jquery`.

This is the way it's supposed to be:

```
    # jQuery
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    # jQuery.ui
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Working great now!

Comment: Im getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function` error in console. Could you please point out to a possible reason? Thanks.

Comment: Then jQueryUI probably is not loading. Check your file for the proper references. [jQueryUI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) Click view source.

Comment: I replaced all the jQuery files (those included in your answer - `jquery.min.js`, `jquery-ui.css` and `jquery-ui.min.js`) with those in the example script on [this page](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but the status has remained the same i.e. still getting the same `.autocomplete is not a function` error. I notice that the `.js` and `.css` files on the linked page are of a different version than those used by you. However, using those has not helped. One thought - I have put the url in the **project root**. Is that how it should be done?

Comment: One other thought. You are referring to an argument `('term','')`. What is it supposed to do and where is it being picked up from? Thanks.

Comment: I had a reference to `jquery.js` at the footer. Removing that made all the difference, no more error and now its working **great**.

Comment: I don't remember on the ```term```. I actually use my own now. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

is it for the reason on the name 'contact-name-search' that cannot been finded ? perhaps lacks of app name or try to change name to 'contact_name_search'